# what is the rule for browser, if used id more than one time on a page?

Tags: css

i look at W3C but not find any rule for browser, all the browser apply the css to all the id, but if you try to use JS than the problem arise.

can any one say me, what is the rule to the browser to do if i used this

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #Button{color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input id="Button" type="button" value="Click me"/>
<input id="Button" type="text" value="Type Here"/>
</form>
</body>
```

> apply the style to only the first element defined with that selector
>
> apply the style to only the last element defined with that selector

i know applying on both is not ture.

Comment: There shouldn't be any rule as that is not valid html. It will probably be vendor specific.

Comment: +1 to counteract the down-vote. This is not a badly written question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standards say that your ids should be unique.

However, browsers are built to cater for ***badly*** written sites, and will happily apply the style to both elements (I think this works for all current browsers).

It does not make it right though! You should avoid this like the plague.

If you want to apply the same style to multiple elements, then use a `class` instead.

```
 <input class="myButton" type="button" value="Click me"/>
```

Comment: Yup - especially if you decide to script anything using those IDs/

Answer (score 2):

The rule is don't use ids more than once. If anything it's going to be browser specific (i.e. unpredictable) because it's not a standard.

Answer (score 1):

IDs must be unique. For what you want to do use a class:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  .Button {color:red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<input class="Button" type="button" value="Click me"/>
<input class="Button" type="text" value="Type Here"/>
</form>
</body>
```